# Is the upcoming release of the Monero GUI v0.14.2.0 or v0.15.0?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm looking/waiting for the version that has the fix which allows the GUI to created view only wallets.

I was using v0.14.0.0 which has the problem and I downloaded v0.14.1.0 and the zip only has a subset of the files/folders that v0.14.0.0 has. Do I copy/paste these files/folders into a folder containing the v0.14.0.0? Is there a release notes file for this release?

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, the current release is GUI v0.14.1.0, which can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/c8eg6k/gui_v01410_boron_butterfly_with_ledger_nano_x_and/

The next release, which is expected to be out soon, is GUI v0.14.1.1. Thereafter, the next release will be GUI v0.15.0.0.

> I downloaded v0.14.1.0 and the zip only has a subset of the files/folders that v0.14.0.0 has.

That is expected. The total amount of files was reduced to improve user experience. Put differently, `monero-wallet-gui.exe` was compiled statically such that the other files did not have to be present in the folder anymore.

> Do I copy/paste these files/folders into a folder containing the v0.14.0.0?

No, simply extract the GUI v0.14.1.0 `.zip` file to a new and separate directory / folder.

> Is there a release notes file for this release?

Yes:

> ## Release notes
>
> - White theme
> - Addressbook redesign
> - History redesign
> - A check update feature that notifies the user (in the GUI) of a new release
> - Trezor Model T and Ledger Nano X support
> - Blockchain pruning
> - Fiat price conversion
> - macOS fullscreen support
> - Various UI/UX improvments
> - Bug fixes and major performance improvements

Comment: Point release comparison commits can also be seen on GitHub: https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/compare/v0.14.1.0...v0.14.1.1